# Why am I getting such odd results from a GroupJoin?

Tags: c#, linq

How do I explain this (badly?)?

I have an entity called "rule" that is a number of "selectors" used to pick out items from a POCO[].  There are a set number of fields to choose from.  All of this is detailed in my database objects.

I need to display the rule in a grid with each rule being a row and each field in the POCO being a column.  Some cells will include a selector, some will not.

I have chosen to use fields.groupJoin(selectors.defaultIfEmpty) to get the cell contents I need:

```
var keyValuesS =
    fields
      .GroupJoin(
          SelectorView.Search(new SelectorViewFilter { RuleId = rule.Id }),
          f => f.Id,
          s => s.FieldId,
          (f, g) => g
            .Select(s => new { 
                key = f.Name + "_S", 
                value = GetToString(f, s) //gets the cell content html
            })
      .DefaultIfEmpty(new { 
                key = f.Name += "_S", 
                value = "<div style='position:relative;height:100%;width:100%'></div>" }) //empty cell
                )
      .SelectMany(g => g)
      .ToDictionary(f => f.key, f => f.value);
```

What I expect is a dictionary with keys being '[field]_S' for every field and values being either the full cell content or the default empty cell.

What I am actually getting is the cells with selectors being '[field]_S_S' but the values are correct.

Add into this that I Union with a second table, 'adjusters' (identical format to 'selectors' but keys have _A) then I get all kinds of mess.  To rub salt in the wound, my own code keeps calling me an _A_S_S!

I have a similar format before, but it was 10x as long, created the html in line but worked.  Now that I have refactored, the same logic no longer works the same.

I'm sure I must be failing to see a simple error in the code.  Please tell me so I can be embarrassed and then get on with the project ^_^

FYI: here is the method including the unions:

```
public static EditableRule PopulateByRule(Rule rule, Field[] fields)
{
    var keyValuesA =
        fields
            .GroupJoin(
                AdjustmentView.Search(new AdjustmentViewFilter { RuleId = rule.Id }),
                f => f.Id,
                a => a.FieldId,
                (f, g) => g
                    .Select(a => new { key = f.Name + "_A", value = GetToString(f, a) })
                    .DefaultIfEmpty(new { key = f.Name += "_A", value = "<div style='position:relative;height:100%;width:100%'></div>" })
            )
            .SelectMany(g => g);
    var keyValuesS =
        fields
            .GroupJoin(
                SelectorView.Search(new SelectorViewFilter { RuleId = rule.Id }),
                f => f.Id,
                s => s.FieldId,
                (f, g) => g
                    .Select(s => new { key = f.Name + "_S", value = GetToString(f, s) })
                    .DefaultIfEmpty(new { key = f.Name += "_S", value = "<div style='position:relative;height:100%;width:100%'></div>" })
            )
            .SelectMany(g => g);
    var keyValuesBoth = keyValuesA.Union(keyValuesS);

    var dictionary = keyValuesBoth.ToDictionary(f => f.key, f => f.value);

    return new EditableRule(rule.Id, rule.DisplayText, dictionary);

}
```

Thanks ^_^

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and output?

Answer (score 1):

I just found my stupid error

The DefaultIdEmpty key has "+=" but should be just + >_<